# Pass and Save data in next page without session(passing but not saving data)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms, post

I will describe the task.
1)There are 2 data in 1 table which I am select them to dropdown by php. I named them: 1)deyis 2)plomb

I have 2 link, first link should show in dropdown menu "deyis" data and second link should show in dropdown menu "plomb" data.

First link php file code:

```html
<?php
$token = trim($_REQUEST["Token"]);
if($tokenData = defineToken($token))
{
 $token=str_replace("==","%3d%3d",$token);
 $token=str_replace("+","%2b",$token);
 $url_t = "MYLINK";
 $p=1;
  
echo "<form action=\"$url_t\" method=\"POST\" id=\"storyForm\">";

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"deyis\" id=\"deyis\" value=$p>";

?>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("storyForm").submit();
</script>
```

And Second link is same, but sends value=2.

In my Index.php file i am getting data by POST

```html
$s=$_POST['plomb'];
if($s==2)
{
 echo "equal to 2";
 
}
$br=$_POST['deyis'];
if($br==1)
{
 
 echo "equal to 1";
}
```

but after I press in same page button wich show data of anything it shows me that "Notice: Undefined index: plomb" and "Notice: Undefined index: deyis".

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Use `GET` to access variables on other pages without using `SESSION` but make sure you know how to use it.

Comment: Ok, İ sent data by POST from one page and received data by GET. Do you mean this?
$s=$_GET['plomb'];

Comment: Like I said: `but make sure you know how to use it`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use local storage also which will pass your data and will save also without session.

like you want to store something do 
`localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");` 
and when you want it back 
`localStorage.getItem("lastname", "Smith");`
and you can remove it after if you want.

just check browser support before use. here:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working fine. I have one more question aboute using it in php. 
I received data by 
`<div id="result"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("plomb");
</script>`

Now i want to add if statement. How is right is to write?

`echo "<script>";
 if(localStorage.getItem("plomb"))
 {
  echo "hi";
 }
echo "</script>";`

Comment: as per me, it would be better not to mix php with java script you will lose code readability. i would suggest try it solving using pure javascript or pure php don't mixup.